# Add and manage two/multiple layouts to an activity in android studio using kotlin language

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view, android-adapter

I am to build an android app using Kotlin language that I understand requires me to use two layouts in the single main activity. The UI that I have to create is shown below.

[image: UI]

The text next like "Vocabulary", "Comprehension and narration", I call as topic.
The others below are subtopics and their counts. Also the topic has a different image from the subtopic. For simplicity sake say I have two images, one for subtopic(bulb_on) and one for topic(pink_band).

Initially I created a single layout to achieve the same. But, what I achieved was same view for both topic and subtopic where in absence of the other default values were filled. So in order to come over this problem. I removed the visibility of the unnecessary fields for topic and subtopic. But again I had the problem of space. So, the next solution I am attempting is two different layouts.

In order to achieve the UI, I have created one layout for the topic and another for subtopic. Now the question I have no clue how to proceed from here because I am an amateur in both kotlin and android-studio. That's why I ask Do I need to add extra method to manage calling/using the two activities?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why should you have two different layouts in Kotlin? You still use `setContentView()` in your main activity and thats it. Please explain what you mean exactly with two layouts.

Comment: @DenisLoh, I have edited the question. Now tell me if what you say still holds.

Comment: You need to design static layout or dynamically grow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me.

Using two different layouts for topic and the subtopic.

The topic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textColor="#d983c0"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Vocabulary" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSymbol"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pink" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The subtopic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_subtopic_title"
    android:textColor="#200"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Subtopic Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_count"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#200"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="count" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_bulb"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulb_on" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_index"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_count"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="no." />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In the adapater, we can call the two layouts using the `getItemViewType`. The code in the adapter should be like:

```
data class MainAdapter(val context: Context ,val items: ArrayList<Any>, val indices: ArrayList<String>, var postList: List<Post>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

val TYPE_TOPIC = 1
val TYPE_SUBTOPIC = 0
var topic=1
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val item = items.get(position) as LinkedHashMap<String,Int>
    if (item.containsValue(-1)){
        return TYPE_TOPIC
    } else {
        return TYPE_SUBTOPIC
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    if (viewType==1) {
        val tlayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.topics, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(tlayout)
    } else {
        val slayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.subtopic, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(slayout)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    if (holder.itemViewType==1) {
            //do something
    }
    else{
          //do something
        }

  }
 }

  class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
  }
```

Thank you androidAhmed, DenisLoh and Mohamed Mohaideen AH for your support.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you can use ScrollView to handle your problem of space or nested ScrollView

or if I have missed understand you can:

you can make two layout and use  to include both in one xml file and use this file in activity or you can use 2 fragments add 2 framelayout in the layout of your activity then open both fragment in your activity